# How to reduce wheels forward jump movement for tank rig?

Tags: rigging

How to reduce wheels forward jump movement when ascending a hill (front wheel goes to far away)

[image]

https://ibb.co/VjXSsSm

Comment: Hi Vivyen, welcome to BSE. Unfortunately we are not mind readers and by just posting a link to a gif - we still have no idea how you did that and that's the reason why we cannot help you. So i would recommend to provide your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ so we don't have to ask in comments about your settings. thx.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos upload only works small files

Comment: @Vivyen Welcome! Stack Exchange is based on the idea that others can learn from our questions, and benefit from the answers we find. To that end, a good Stack Exchange question has all the information that a reader would need to understand 1) the problem you're encountering, and 2) what you've already tried to solve it.
If you need someone to help you diagnose a problem that you're not sure how to describe, your post would be better suited for a BlenderArtists forum. Once you nail down your question, feel free to come back here and update your question for the benefit of others! Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.